# Why two appearances of the past participle "ganado" in this derivation?

Tags: syntax-trees, movement, derivation

The sentence being parsed:

De CHOMSKY varios libros han ganado premios internacionales, no de Trotsky.

of Chomsky several books have won awards international-PL, not of Trotsky

[image]

Could someone please tell me why there are two *ganado*'s? Much obliged!

Comment: I@m far from an expert, but it looks like a mistake to me.

Comment: I don’t know much about Spanish, but typically the verb is base-generated in V, which then usually moves to Spec,vP (but then it gets deleted in V).

Comment: @AlexB. That's what I was confused about! Thank you for explaining this to me. And if I may raise another doubt about this derivation, why is the PP on the top "De Chomsky" moved from the "de Chomsky" in Spec(v*P) as opposed to the "de Chomksy" in Spec(TP)?

Answer (score 5):

One of the main reasons for positing a *v* layer separate from V is the behavior of ditransitive verbs. In particular, all the objects of a ditransitive verb seem to form a constituent of their own, separate from the verb: *I gave (the books to Alice) and (the papers to Bob)*.

This can be explained if we assume that V selects all its objects, and then a separate *v* selects the subject, and finally V moves to the position of *v* (head movement). Then we can say that the objects are all inside the VP, forming a constituent, and the verb appears outside it (at the position of *v*).

That's presumably what's happening here. The verb *ganado* is generated at V position, and then moved to *v* (or copied and then the original is deleted if you prefer). The lower copy should have a strikethrough to indicate this, and I'm guessing it's just an error that it's not. Certainly we don't see two copies of the word *ganado* on the surface.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you SO MUCH! And if I may express another doubt about this derivation, why is the PP on the top "De Chomsky" moved from the "de Chomsky" in Spec(v*P) as opposed to the "de Chomksy" in Spec(TP)?

Comment: @Jenny There's only one "de Chomsky" PP. It's often taken as an axiom that movement happens as the tree is being built, triggered by something in the root projection. If you take this axiom, at some point T is merged in, and its EPP feature attracts the nearest DP; this DP moves _in its entirety_, including the PP inside it. Then later C is merged in, and its Foc feature attracts the PP.

Comment: Right, so, excuse me for being a bit slow-witted here, but I just want to be sure I am not mistaken in this. Are you saying that after PP is moved up along with the entire DP to Spec (TP), C probes into Spec (TP), and extracts PP, then places it in Spec (CP)?

Comment: @Jenny Yes, I believe so. I'm not sure what particular theory this comes from, so you may have to do some additional trickery involving the PP moving to SpecD (do they discuss "phases" at all?), but that's the gist of it.